# slideup and slide down with animate easing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideup, slidedown, jquery-easing

I need a smooth slide effect and i cant seem to understand what I am doing wrong. I have tried the following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.drop2').click(function(){
       var $next = $(this).parent().next('li.drop_down2');
       if($next.is(':visible')) {
           $next.animate(     {'display':'none'}, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
       } else {
         $next.animate(   {'display':'block'}, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
       }
   });
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.drop2').click(function(){
       var $next = $(this).parent().next('li.drop_down2');
       if($next.is(':visible')) {
           $next.slideUp({
           duration: 1000, 
           easing: easeInSine, 
           complete: callback});
       } else {
           $next.slideDown();
       }
   });
  });
```

Is there something I am doing wrong to make this smooth effect happen

Comment: Please use the code tag so we understand what it is you are posting. Also tell us what browser you are testing this on. IE is stupidly slow at javascript.

Comment: Is the problem that it isn't smooth, or that it doesn't work at all?

Comment: @Iznogood: My question was for Matt. Sorry that wasn't clear. I agree, his code is hard to read. My complaint is that he describes no symptoms.

Comment: @Mark oups I really tought he was posting that question sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, Matt:

```
<div class="trigger"><a href="#" onclick="return false">Expand one.</a></div>
<div class="expander">Item one is now shown.</div>

<div class="trigger"><a href="#" onclick="return false">Expand two.</a></div>
<div class="expander">Item two is now shown.</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.expander').hide();
    jQuery('.trigger').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next('.expander').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```